# How to use wingdings in java

Tags: java, wingdings

How to display wingdings2  symbols in java. I tried googling but i couldn't find much help.

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html

Please refer the above link. I would like to display the white diamond symbol.

Comment: please state your usecase and give us some code that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Wingdings is a font-based trick

The old Wingdings was a hack, a font that used alternate designs as the glyph. For example, where a NUMBER SIGN (pound sign, hash mark) was expected when using character position 35, a fountain pen image appears instead.

For this hack to succeed, (a) the user must have the desired Wingdings font installed, and (b) the text being displayed must use that font specifically.

## Unicode

Nowadays, it likely makes sense to use [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) or other image characters defined among the 143,859 characters in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Those characters are each assigned a number, a [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point), using numbers over the range of about a million.

Perhaps this character would work for you: `◇` [Unicode Character 'WHITE DIAMOND' (U+25C7)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c7/index.htm) at decimal code point 9,671.

```
System.out.println( "◇ = WHITE DIAMOND" ) ;
```

Your user needs a font, any font, that provides a [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) for that particular character. Modern OSes are skilled at automatically finding and using a secondary font with such a glyph if a displayed text block’s primary font is lacking. Understand that no single font provides a glyph for each and every character in Unicode.

There are likely other diamond-related characters too that a search might expose.

As a Java programmer, you can simply paste your desired character into your source code. Be sure to use UTF-8 as the character encoding of your file.